# Multiple file with same name is not uploading in loopback

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, loopbackjs, file-rename

I am uploading the files using the REST API url Loopback3. Once the form is submitted the values are inserted and the files is getting saved. Now if i upload the file with the same which already exits the file is not getting stored.How to rename the file followed by some random number and save.

HTML

```
<form  id="myForm" novalidate class="formval" >
    <div class="form-row">
       <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
       <div class="form-group col-md-12">
         <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
       <div class="form-group col-md-8">
          <input type="file"  id="resume" class="form-control" name="resume" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf" required />
       </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-10" id="item-submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Script:

```
  var $firstname, $lastname, $message, $resume, $inserted_date, ins_date;


var apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/';

$(document).ready(function() {
   var random = Math.random( ); 
    $('#myForm').on('submit', handleForm);
     ins_date=new Date($.now()).toLocaleString();
    $firstname = $('#firstname');
    $lastname = $('#lastname');
    $message = $('#message');
    $resume = $('#resume');
    $inserted_date=ins_date;
});


function handleForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var career = {
      firstname:$firstname.val(),
      lastname:$lastname.val(),
      message:$message.val(),
      inserted_date:ins_date
    }
    console.log(career);
    $.post(apiUrl + 'careers', career).then(function(res) {
        career = res;
        var promises = [];
        if($resume.val() != '') {
            console.log('i need to process the resume upload');
            promises.push(sendFile($resume.get(0).files[0], apiUrl + 'attachments/resume/upload'));
        }
        Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
            console.log('back from all promises', results);
            if(promises.length >= 1) {
                results.forEach(function(resultOb) {
                    if(resultOb.result.files && resultOb.result.files.file[0].container) {
                     career[resultOb.result.files.file[0].container] = resultOb.result.files.file[0].name;
                    }
                });
                console.dir(career);
                var id = career.id;
                delete career.id;
                $.post(apiUrl + 'careers/'+id+'/replace', career).then(function() {
                });
            } else {
            }
        });

    });

}

function sendFile(file, url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var fd = new FormData();
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            }
        };
        fd.append('file', file);
        xhr.send(fd);
        $(".alert-success").removeClass("d-none");
          $(".alert-success").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
            $(".alert-success").slideUp(500);
         });
          $('#myForm')[0].reset();
    });
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you handle this on your backend(API) instead of frontend. If you want this on frontend you can prepend current timestamp to filename like this: ```fd.append('file', file, `${Date.now()}_${file.name}`);``` Put timestamp before filename to preserve file extension.

Comment: can you please edit in my code and explain

Comment: Replace your line `fd.append('file', file);` inside `sendFile` method with ```fd.append('file', file, `${Date.now()}_${file.name}`);```. If it works for you I will add an answer with explanation. Notice its not single quotes around `${Date.now()}_${file.name}`, it's the button above `Tab` on your keyboard, it called `backtick` or `back-quote`

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved my day it works for me

Comment: Great, I will add an answer with proper explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using the [loopback-component-storage](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Storage-component.html#automatic-unique-filenames).

I would advise to simply use the `nameConflict` attribute when creating your datasource, like in the following example - since it looks like you already retrieve the filename that has been uploaded:

In your Loopback's **server/server.js**

```
var ds = loopback.createDataSource({
    connector: require('loopback-component-storage'),
    provider: 'filesystem',
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'attachments'),
    nameConflict: 'makeUnique' // simply add this line!
});

var container = ds.createModel('attachments');
```

Comment: can we get the attached file name in the js file

Comment: Didn't you already do this in this line: 'resultOb.result.files.file[0].name' ?

Comment: can you answer over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55470821/get-attached-file-name-in-attachment-js-using-loopback

Comment: should i use this resultOb.result.files.file[0].name  in the attachment.js file

Comment: You just store this result as a property of your model so you can retrieve it later.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what problem exactly it is. Please open a new detailled question on what your new problem is.

Comment: I have opened a new question can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55534760/loopback-how-to-accesss-from-one-model-to-another-and-send-email

Answer (score 1):

You need to add something unique to filename each file uploaded. The easiest(probably not the best) way is to add the current timestamp.

The syntax for appending files to FormData object is: `formData.append(name, value);` or  `formData.append(name, value, filename);`. If you use the first version and skip the `filename` argument it defaults to the `name` attribute of `file`. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

In your case you don't want the default filename you need to add timestamp to it.
You can get current timestamp using `Date.now()` or `new Date().getTime()`. It's better to use `Date.now()` in this case because it's more than two times faster(and less typing too) than `new Date().getTime()`.

So you can now generate a unique filename like this:

```
`${Date.now()}_${file.name}`
```

We put time first because `file.name` contains file extension and you want that.
This will generate something like this `'1553690001341_whatever.jpg'`
But if put filename first you will get `'whatever.jpg_1553690001341'` and so the file will not be saved with a file extension on server and if someone downloads it from server they will not know how to open it.

Also we use backticks to use variables inside string, it just makes things a little easier. If you don't use backticks you can get the same result using `+` like this:

```
Date.now() + '_' + file.name
```

Now all you need to do is to add filename too when appending file to FormData. So write

```
fd.append('file', file, `${Date.now()}_${file.name}`);
```

instead of

```
fd.append('file', file);
```

**PS:** Things like these should be handled by backend API

Comment: how can i get the file name in the loopback model.js file

Comment: I have never used loopback, I use python for api. But you can search google for it I am pretty sure there is already an answer for it on stackoverflow.

Comment: Looks like you need: `file.originalname` [File Upload With Loopback](//stackoverflow.com/a/43410296)

Comment: how to get the filename

Answer (score 0):

As I have read your request, I understood that you are trying to upload file using loopback. Even the upload using loopback is working fine, but your request is to upload file with same name right?

If it is you are store the files using versioning by adding some key text at the end line'_v1' where you can check the increment the value on new upload. Or else a easy method will be you can concatenate timestamp in Unix format, which will be series of number and will be unique for every second. So you can save this name in DB for your reference.

eg:

```
var filename = filename +'_'+ new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: can you please give some example with code or u can edit the above code

Comment: var filename = filename +'_'+ new Date().getTime();  this will give you unique filename always

Comment: I can able to rename but i could not insert or store. it is throwing this error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Answer (score 0):

Loopback can rename files itself when saving:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Storage-component.html#renaming-files

Comment: can we get the file name in the attachment.js file, where attachment is my module for file storage